# net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for value

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I am storing Set of values into the memcached client with key as setOfKeys.
I am putting the value in the memcached as follows

```
Set<String> keys=new HashSet<String>();
mMemcachedClient = new MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(),
                AddrUtil.getAddresses("172.22.65.111:11211 172.22.65.11:11211"));

public void put(Object key, Object value) throws Result {

        try {
            synchronized (mMemcachedClient) {
                this.keys.add(key.toString());

                if(keys.size()==1){
                    mMemcachedClient.set(String.valueOf(hg.hash("setOfKeys")),
                            7200, keys);
                }
                else{
                    mMemcachedClient.replace(String.valueOf(hg.hash("setOfKeys")),
                            7200, keys);
                }
                mMemcachedClient.set(String.valueOf(hg.hash(key.toString())),
                        7200, value);
            }
        } catch (Excep`enter code here`tion ex) {`enter code here`
            mLogger.error(ex.getMessage());
            throw new Result("ERROR_PUT_MEMCACHED_INTO_CACHE");
        }
    }
```

But when i try to fetch setOfKeys from the cache as follows it give me the error

`net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set and replace functions in MemcachedClient are asynchronous and return Futures. You must call .get() on the returned object in order to get it to block until the operation is completed.

```
mMemcachedClient.set(String.valueOf(hg.hash("setOfKeys")), 7200, keys).get();
```

You should also check the returned value of the statement above in order to make sure the operation was successful.

Comment: When i have only my Local server In memcached client as mMemcachedClient = new MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(),
    AddrUtil.getAddresses("172.22.65.111:11211")); .That time it works fine.But when i Increase servers Like mMemcachedClient = new MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(),
    AddrUtil.getAddresses("172.22.65.111:11211 172.22.65.11:11211"));.Its does work. It gave me Exceptiion net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for value.

Comment: Try connecting to 172.22.65.11 with telnet and send some commands and see if that works. If it doesn't then you either have networking issues or the memcached on that machine is not functioning properly.

Comment: Thanx alot...Issue was having with other server.After Re-installing that server no eXception came..Thanx again.